# IntegrityError when trying to create a one to many relationship in Python Django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, one-to-many

I am a beginner developer, working on an app that displays some walks, and each walk should have an option for users to post reviews.

I am trying to create a relationship between Walk and Review models. Each Walk should have multiple Reviews, but each Review should only belong to one Walk.

I'm trying to create a one-to-many relationship, but keep getting IntegrityError like so:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'walks_walk' with
> primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: walks_walk.reviews_id
> contains a value '2' that does not have a corresponding value in
> reviews_review.id.

Here are my models:

Walk

```
from django.db import models

from reviews.models import Review


class Walk(models.Model):
    # walk ID automatically generated
    walk_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    walk_reviews = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="No reviews yet")
```

Review

```
from datetime import date
from operator import mod
from statistics import mode
from tkinter import CASCADE
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User # change to updated bespoke User model vs built-in

class Review(models.Model):
    # Review ID auto-created
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
```

I have tried several variations and cleared out my test database data, but the issue persists. What can be the cause, and how can I solve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of software engineering!

It sounds counter intuititive but what you want to do is relate the Review to the Walk not the Walk to the Reviews.

```py
class Review(models.Model):
    # Review ID auto-created
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    walk = models.ForeignKey(Walk, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then when you create a review, refence it to the walk it was created for.

The way you've designed it is that a walk can only have a single review.

Also take a look at the Django docs for 'related_name' so you can give the walk object a property name that makes sense to refer to all its related reviews like 'all_reviews' or something

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!